# Split the string based on regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I've an array of strings like `Name`, `Groups[0].Id`, `Types[11].Name`.

I want to filter the string that has square brackets and split them into two parts. For ex., `Groups[0].Id` into  `Groups` and `Id`.

How I can find the strings that has square brackets using regular expression?

Comment: I was confused by your question?  Did you want to filter the string or the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
Regex.Split(input,@"\[.*?\][.]");
```

Comment: Would it be better to use a `\d` rather than a `.`? presuming that the value in the `[]` is always a decimal. i.e. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?35pd2

Comment: @Liam: what if it is an associative array keyed by strings?

Answer (score 2):

Just for splitting a single string like

```
string value = "Groups[0].Id";
```

use

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(value, "\[\d+\]\.");
```

Explanation: you have to escape the square bracket and dot characters with a backslash (they have special meanings within a regular expression) and \d+ will accept only a string of number digits ('0'..'9') with at least one digit.

Links:

- A nice .NET regex test page is http://regexhero.net/
- MSDN documentation on Regex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you wanted to split the strings which is implied by your question title, or filter the list which seems to be what your asking at the end. You can split each element of the array with brackets and a periods this regex.  This regex does not assume that the indices are digits alone -- for example it will allow an array keyed by strings.

```
Regex.Split(a, @"\[[^\]]+\]\.");
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/pg1skt1j)

You can use LINQ to Filter the array in one line.

```
string[] ary = new string[3] {"Name", "Groups[0].Id", "Types[11].Name" };

ary = ary.Where(a => Regex.Match(a, @"\[[^\]]+\]\.").Success).ToArray();

foreach (string str in ary)
{
     Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```